# PTX to target translation in OpenCl

Tags: java, opencl, bytecode, ptx

In OpenCL the "PTX (like bytecode in java) to target converter" is an interpreter (like we have for bytecode in java) or an ahead-of-time assembler?

Answer (score 1):

Java is just-in-time compiled, not interpreted.

PTX is also compiled at loadtime.

Not sure about OpenCL, but CUDA can also store pre-compiled binaries for a given set of architectures in the executable (and JIT the rest). It is an option in the CUDA compiler.

Comment: In Java the same bytecode if encountered is translated again by JVM. What about PTX, will it also be translated again and again?

Comment: The JVM caches the machine code until it its shut down, but won't modify the executable to store it. Same thing with PTX.

Comment: So then why is PTX conversion not slow?

Comment: Define slow. Compiling bytecode is fairly quick but still takes noticeable time.